# Can't use custom 3D model for visualization

Tags: openmodelica

I'm using the `Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Visualizers.FixedShape` to render custom 3D models. I tried using `.dxf` and `.stl` in ASCII format but none works.
For `.dxf` I get no error but the model doesn't show up.
For `.stl` I get an error saying there is no plugin for that file type.

Comment: Note that dxf is a messy format, so to get the best help it is preferable to include the actual dxf-file (or a similar one) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please see the highlighted portions in the above image. OpenModelica supports adding an external shape using the format `shapeType=modelica://<Modelica-name>/<relative-path-file-name>`. Preferably create a `Resources` folder  in the same level under the library folder and add `dxf` files in them. The following animation shows the same. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Yes I followed the same. Created a project Package. Then reference it as "modelica://MyPackage/Resources/1.dxf". No error, but the 3D object does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably [broken](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/9503) when you attempted it but has been fixed in OMEdit 1.21+.  The stl in this model did not animate in 1.20 but does in 1.21+:

```
model stlsFixed
  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world annotation(    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape bodyShape(m = 10, r = {0.5, 0, 0}, r_CM = {0.25, 0, 0}, shapeType = "file://C:/absolute/path/to/stl.stl")  annotation(    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {30, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.FreeMotion freeMotion annotation(    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(world.frame_b, freeMotion.frame_a) annotation(    Line(points = {{-40, 0}, {-20, 0}}));
  connect(freeMotion.frame_b, bodyShape.frame_a) annotation(    Line(points = {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}));
annotation(    Diagram(coordinateSystem(initialScale = 0.08)),    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end stlsFixed;
```